# JAXB marshaller using Java member variable convention

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I'm currently trying to figure out why JAXB marshaller uses Java member variable convention as opposed to follow the XmlType annotation.

Here's the situation:

- Third-party gave us XSD
- We use JDK tools to generate Java classes
- The generated Java classes produced correct annotation: @XmlType(name = "XML_DOCUMENT_TYPE")

But when I tried to marshal the class back to XML, JAXB converts it to `<xmlDocumentType>` instead of `<XML_DOCUMENT_TYPE>`

Any idea why? (If so, how can I fix this?)

Update: to clarify, the issue occurred at the top/root level element, not at the sub element/member variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE (based on comment by xandross**

You can use `@XmlRootElement` to control the root element name:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="XML_DOCUMENT_TYPE")
public class Foo {
  ...
}
```

Alternatively you can wrap the root object in an instance of `JAXBElement` to supply root element information.

---

**UPDATE** (based on comment by Mohamed Mansour)

In JAXB classes correspond to XML types, and fields/properties correspond to XML attributes/elements.  This makes sense when you consider there may exist an address type:

```
<xs:complexType name="address">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="street" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

and multiple elements (with different names) that are of that type:

```
<xs:complexType name="customer">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="billing-address type="address"/>
        <xs:element name="shipping-address type="address"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

You can control the name of the element/attribute that a property maps to with the `@XmlElement`/`@XmlAttribute` annotations:

```
@XmlElement(name="shipping-address")
public getShippingAddress() {
    return shippingAddress;
}
```

or

```
@XmlElement(name="ShippingAddress")
public getShippingAddress() {
    return shippingAddress;
}
```

If the property is not annotated it is treated as `@XmlElement` and the element name is derived from the property name.

Comment: Hi Blaise, I believe he was referring to a subtype that he is using. For example within his main type he has `private SomeType xmlDocumentType;` So in this case, he needs to add an `@XmlElement(name="XML_DOCUMENT_TYPE")` at the field level, because JAXB uses the field name instead of the `@XmlType` name.

Comment: @Mohamed Mansour - You are correct, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Actually I am referring to the root element. Sub elements or fields are easy to deal with. Sorry for the missing information.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more what you mean with using a JAXBElement wrapper (and the assumed output if possible)? Thanks!

Comment: @xandross - This example demonstrates how JAXBElement can be used to supply root element information:  http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted/TheBasics